# Multiple "Set-Cookie" fields in NextJS-getServerSideProps?

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js

In getServerSideProps I need to set multiple cookies on client device. I coded:
[image]

Answer (score 32):

You can likely use an array for the second argument.

```js
ctx.res.setHeader('set-cookie', ['access-token=1', 'refresh-token=1'])
```

In Next.js, the `req` and `res` objects are just Node.js HTTP objects. So anything you can do in Node.js you can do with Next.js.

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value

Answer (score 9):

Since the `res.setHeader` function in the NextJS context variable is just a NodeJS `http` module Response object, you can set multiple values for a header like so:

```js
res.setHeader('set-cookie', ['val1', 'val2'];
```

This behavior is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_setheader_name_value) in the NodeJS docs:

> Use an array of strings here to send multiple headers with the same name.

Answer (score 4):

###### Do like This:

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
    cookie.serialize(
        'access', user.tokens.access, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
            maxAge: 60 * 30,
            sameSite: 'strict',
            path: '/api/'
        }
    ),
    cookie.serialize(
        'refresh', user.tokens.refresh, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
            sameSite: 'strict',
            path: '/api/'
        }
    )
]);
```

Comment: it seems that you are using a special library: you probably want to include the import of the library and show how to use it. Especially as the API for that lib can change.

Comment: its an npm package called cookie